# Como inserir um where dentro de uma query do linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
var result = (from line in db.ApadrinhamentoListas
    group new { line } by new { line.datahora, line.valor_doacao } 
    into grp 
    select new 
    {
      DataHora = grp.Key.datahora,
      Valor = grp.Key.valor_doacao
    }).OrderBy(o => o.DataHora);
```

E gostaria de colocar um *where* no meio disso para puxar os valores apenas de um cnpj específico. No caso essa *query* retorna todos os apadrinhamentos que estão cadastrados no banco, mas eu gostaria que retornasse da ong específica que está logada, no banco tenho o campo `ong_receptora`, que possui o cnpj da mesma, e também consigo recuperar o cnpj da ong logada, porém não sei como fazer tal comparação na *query*.

Comment: o cnpj está dentro `ApadrinhamentoListas` ?

Comment: No ApadrinhamentoListas tenho o campo ong_receptora, que possui o cnpj da ong, e através de um método eu consigo pegar o cnpj da ong logada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É simples só criar a variável com o valor do `CNPJ` e fazer um `Where`, igual exemplo abaixo:

```
var cnpj = "valor do cnpj";
var result = (from line in db.ApadrinhamentoListas where line.ong_receptora == cnpj
    group new { line } by new { line.datahora, line.valor_doacao } 
    into grp 
    select new 
    {
      DataHora = grp.Key.datahora,
      Valor = grp.Key.valor_doacao
    }).OrderBy(o => o.DataHora);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = (from line in db.ApadrinhamentoListas
    where line.ong_receptora == "valor"
    group new { line } by new { line.datahora, line.valor_doacao } 
    into grp 
    select new 
    {
      DataHora = grp.Key.datahora,
      Valor = grp.Key.valor_doacao
    }).OrderBy(o => o.DataHora);
```

ou

```
 var result = (from line in db.ApadrinhamentoListas.
        where(x=>x.ong_receptora.equals("valor"))
        group new { line } by new { line.datahora, line.valor_doacao } 
        into grp 
        select new 
        {
          DataHora = grp.Key.datahora,
          Valor = grp.Key.valor_doacao
        }).OrderBy(o => o.DataHora);
```